# SQL group by (?) query not returning as required

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a sql table (see the .jpg included). 
Some products, like 100 and 103 have the card value as 1300 but some products, like  101, don't. I need to create a sql query to identify products that don't have the 1300 card and return only those cards. 
My group by query did not achieve this.

[image]

Comment: You don't need to use `GROUP BY` if you are just trying to find out which products don't have `card = 1300`... you can just do `SELECT * FROM <table> t WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM <table> z WHERE z.product_id = t.product_id AND z.card = 1300);` (or something similar)

Comment: A better approach to ask this question would be to post the query that you have tried as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
select product_id
from your_table
group by product_id
having sum(card = 1300) = 0
```

Comment: This works the best, and includes a `GROUP BY` as requested in the original question.

Comment: Define "works the best". I have a feeling a GROUP BY will be more expensive than a join or subquery in this case.

Comment: Let me rephrase... is the easiest, most concise, and specifically what the OP was asking for. I don't think that any performance issues would be noticeable until there are thousands and thousands of rows.

Comment: I highly doubt your query would be faster but you can measure the performance if you like @DrunkenCodeMonkey. Maybe the `exists` query of dubStylee is faster but that needs to be measured

Comment: This actually appears to be invalid syntax for SQL Server. I guess the tag threw me off. I have a posted an answer with a comparison in the execution plan for different approaches  on MSSQL.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, you can do it without a `GROUP BY` clause. @DrunkenCodeMonkey beat me to the answer while I was putting together a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba5429/3) to show it in action.

```
select *
from products as t
where not exists (select * 
                  from products as z 
                  where z.product_id = t.product_id and z.card = 1300);
```

Both `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` will work.

Answer (score 1):

**Not equal `<>` operator**

You can use `<>` or `!=` operator in `where` clause with `group by`

```
SELECT product_id
from table_name
where card <> 1300
group by product_id;
```

OR

```
SELECT product_id
from table_name
where card != 1300
group by product_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. First get a list of the product IDs to exclude, and then get rows for all the other entries:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE product_id NOT IN (SELECT product_id
                         FROM MyTable
                         WHERE card = 1300)
```

Here is a comparison on the execution plan of different approaches on MSSQL. The first two yield the exact same result, but the third, which is the closest approximation to MySQL's GROUP BY...HAVING SUM(card = 1300) = 0, is definitely more expensive because of the group by's aggregate and sort.

[image]